# Updating a value in an array using a function - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and I've found myself slightly confused.

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("calcController", function($scope) {
 $scope.interests=[{time:'month',amount:0},
                 {time:'quarter',amount:0},
                 {time:'year',amount:0}];

 $scope.rates=[{rate:0.01,lower:0,upper:1000,desc:'£0 - £1000'},
             {rate:0.02,lower:1000,upper:5000,desc:'£1000 - £5000'},
             {rate:0.03,lower:5000,upper:'none',desc:'£5000+'},];

 $scope.balance=0;
 $scope.updatedIntAmount=function(balance){
   if(balance<0){
       return 0;
   }
   else if(balance>=rates[1].lower && balance<rates[1].upper){
       return balance*rates[1].rate;
   }
   else if(balance>=rates[2].lower && balance<rates[2].upper){
       return balance*rates[2].rate;
   }
   else {
       return balance*rates[3].rate;
   }
 }
});
```

What I want is some way to bind the value of `interests.amount` to `updatedIntAmount`.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="calcController" class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="balInput">Balance:</label>
    <input id="balInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="balance">
  </div> 
  <p ng-repeat="interest in interests">{{'per '+interest.time+':'+interest.amount}}</p>
</div>
```

So what I have is `interests.amount` dependent on `calculateIntAmount`, which in turn is dependent on both `rates.rate` and `balance`. How can I get these `interests.amount` values to change whenever `balance` is updated?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of a change in balance resulting in a subsequent change in interests.amount?

Comment: Can you not make interests.amount values equal to some calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng-change` to your input field like so `<input id="balInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="balance" ng-change="updatedIntAmount(balance)">`. This will allow you to call the function on a change to the input field and thus do whatever you want within the function in your controller.

You can learn more at the official [AngularJS documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `$scope.$watch` to observe any changes in your `balance` variable, and then update your `interests.amount` accordingly.

In your controller, you would have:

```
$scope.$watch('balance', function(newBalance) {
  $scope.interests.amount = $scope.updatedIntAmount(newBalance);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of errors are present in your code.

as first there is nothing like rates[1] instead you should change it to $scope.rates[1].

Second : your updatedIntAmount function contains rates[3] which is again wrong as you have rates[2] as max limit according to array index rule.

Your updatedIntAmount function return a single value based upon the balance is inserted. in that case after correcting the errors just add :

```
{{updatedIntAmount(balance)}}
```

in your html code. it will change as soon as change in balance.

```
 $scope.updatedIntAmount=function(balance){
 if(balance<0){
     return 0;
 }
 else if(balance>=$scope.rates[0].lower && balance<$scope.rates[0].upper){
     return balance*$scope.rates[0].rate;
 }
 else if(balance>=$scope.rates[1].lower && balance<$scope.rates[1].upper){
     return balance*$scope.rates[1].rate;
 }
 else {
     return balance*$scope.rates[2].rate;
 }
 }
```